# Syncing Google Calendar with iPhone Alarms

Tags: iphone, calendar

Does anyone know if there is a way to make google calendar alerts more intrusive on an iPhone? Currently, you just get a weak push notificiation, which is very easy to be ignored by accident.

One way would be to automatically sync calendar events with phone alarms (which are very intrusive, as they have to be manually disabled by users).

Is something like this possible with a jailbroken iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to choose a long and loud ringtone as your calendar alert sound. Try it, it works, and doesn't require any technical manipulation. You can change the alert from the preferences (and not within calendar itself).

You will probably have to make a ringtone yourself if the regular ones seem too harmless... A ringtone can be as long as 30 seconds. Here is how to make one: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-make-ringtones-for-iphone/

You can also set a second alarm in calendar for an event. It will be hard to miss two consecutive alerts of 30 seconds!

Comment: This is a great idea. My phone is often set on vibrate mode.  Is there a way for it vibrate constantly for 30 seconds as well?

Comment: Nevermind -- I figured out how to do this within the preferences section.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @user1770201 can you please go over the solution you found? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me!

1. Synchronize Apple Calendar and Google Calendar by going to Settings -> Calendar -> Accounts -> Gmail(sign in to your account) -> turn on sync Calendars. As long as the notification is set up on Google Calendar, it will also notify you on Apple calendar.
2. Then you can go to Settings -> Calendar Alerts. There you can set up a ringtone of your choosing that is long.
   Voila! Your notifications should now behave just like an alarm.

Note:

- Adding events to Apple Calendar will not add them to Google Calendar, but the other way around works! Add events to Google Calendar as usual.